# ADF / WCP Popup if client state is lost

Tags: javascript, popup, oracle-adf

I'm using JDev `11.1.1.7.0`, WCP `11.1.1.8.0`, I am trying to override the following on the popup that is displayed when the view state is lost (when your configured value for `CLIENT_STATE_MAX_TOKENS` is less than the number of view states consumed):

> Because of inactivity, your session has timed out and is no longer active. Click OK to reload the page.

To do this, I checked the values in `AdfDhtmlLookAndFeel.__TRANSLATIONS` in the browser and found that `MSGPPRViewExpired` is the key for the above message. In my skin bundle I specified a new value for `MSGPPRViewExpired` and can see the value reflecting in the browser debugger. However when the popup shows up, it still displays the older message.

Update 1 -
Also decompiled `oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.resource.RichBundle` and it has `MSGPPRViewExpired` as the key. Not sure why the popup still displays the default text.

Update 2-
Also tried this -

```
    FacesContext facesContext = phaseEvent.getFacesContext();
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    try {
        res.getWriter().write("<script>AdfDhtmlLookAndFeel.__TRANSLATIONS['MSGPPRViewExpired']='Sorry.. Something went wrong, we are gonna have to reload the page'</script>");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle
    }
```

inside `beforePhase` and `afterPhase` of a phaselistener (`ANY_PHASE`). It also does update the message and can be seen in the console but the popup still displays the default text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so if anyone faces the same problem, here is the solution and it is not very recommended but is the only way as far as i know -

Some keys like `MSGPPRViewExpired` are not customizable directly, so the way to go is to override the default `RichBundle` for your locale. For eg, add `en` as your supported locale in `faces-config` and then specify something like this -

```
    package oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.resource;

    import java.util.ListResourceBundle;

    public class RichBundle_en extends ListResourceBundle {


        @Override
        public Object[][] getContents() {
            return new Object[][] { { "MSGPPRViewExpired", "Boom! New Message!" } };
        }
    }
```

And boom.

@Nagh, thanks for all your suggestions.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, however it looks like this message is bundled with you current skin. So all you need is to override skin message bundle and write you own message there with this key `MSGPPRViewExpired`.

In your skin create resource file.
Register this bundle in `trinindad-skins.xml` like this:

```
<bundle-name>resources.skinBundle</bundle-name>
```

Depends on type of the bundle create proper record with `MSGPPRViewExpired` key and the desired text.

Actually it seems that right keys for this message are:

```
af_document.POST_SESSION_TIMEOUT_ALERT_TITLE
af_document.POST_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MSG
af_document.POST_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MSG_CONTINUE
```

Also here is more keys for this kind of message:

```
af_document.PRE_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MSG
af_document.PRE_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MSG_SECOND
af_document.PRE_SESSION_TIMEOUT_CONFIRM_TITLE
```

Comment: That's what I did in the first place, and it also reflects in AdfTranslations js file, but the popup still displays the orginal text. :|

Comment: Ok, let me do some research. There is also same message in the main bundle

Comment: @navaneet.agarwal it seems that there should be another keys, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Nagh, but, I tried them all, same result. One thing you must have seen is that if you look through all the strings in AdfTranslations or by decompiling default Resource bundle, `MSGPPRViewExpired ` is the key for the message in my OP, for all the other keys the strings are different ones.

Comment: @navaneet.agarwal did you try to change the same way (through bundle) some other strings? Did it work? I've made sample on 12c with 11.1.1.7 theme and it was working as expected. May be you can build sample application and let me look wthat is wrong there?

Comment: Yes, I did through the skinBundle. Are you sure changes made to `MSGPPRViewExpired ` are reflecting? I have modified other resource strings in the past and they work fine but it is only in this case that is not working

Comment: @navaneet.agarwal not exactly. I set session timeout to 1 min in web.xml and just let the simple form to expire. Message that was shown was regulated by this keys, I've mentioned in my answer first - `af_document.POST_SESSION_TIMEOUT_ALERT_TITLE`, etc. Have you tried this keys?

Comment: Yes, but by default, `af_document.POST_SESSION_TIMEOUT_ALERT_TITLE` displays _Page Expired_ as the message. You can test my case by setting `org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CLIENT_STATE_MAX_TOKENS` to 1 in your `web.xml` and then opening your app in two tabs, and then going back to the first tab. In this case, the message displayed is regulated by `MSGPPRViewExpired`. Again, appreciate your help.

Comment: @navaneet.agarwal unfortunately I can't reproduce it. However its not clear test case, since I'm using 12c version. Can you build very simple sample app to demonstrate this effect?

Comment: @navaneet.agarwal  take a look at [this sample, last part](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/22-expand-adf-faces-messages-169160.pdf) Could be your case, since MSGPPRViewExpired resides actually in RichBundle.

Comment: Tried overriding RichBundle as well, again, can see it updated in the browser debugger but the popup still displays the same message! :|